# Android Automotive Bring Up from standard Android device tree

Tags: android, android-automotive, automotive, aaos

I was doing some android automotive related stuffs. For that i need to build AAOS for a specific board which doesn't have AAOS support and have android support. So i'm planing to make canges to available android device tree so that it can boot AAOS.
The issue is that, I'm not sure about what all changes are needed for automotive.

I have compared a official aaos sources with android source. After adding those changes to my build, it still boots th android

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

See https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/start/avd/android_virtual_device

Consider to use AAOS emulator build as starting point.

[sdk_car_x86_64](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:device/generic/car/sdk_car_x86_64.mk) build files can be a good reference.

Comment: I gone through that already. But didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: If you build by using AAOS emulator build target (sdk_car_x86_64), you can see launching of AAOS emulator from your local build. You can see build files of AAOS emulator source codes to make sure how you can build for AAOS not mobile.